# How do I create a dockerized development environment for ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I have developed a react app via the includes live-server and deployed it. As a proxy server I am using nginx, which also serves some static and media files for the back- and frontend.

Especially to test the serving of static and media files I would like to have a dockerized local testing environment.

**Here is my problem:** 
In my test environment I do not want to create a new build every time I change the code (`npm run build` - for create-react-app). Ideally, I would have the ability to hot-reload via a bind mount.

This would mean that I would have to serve the development server via nginx. Is that at all possible? I am biting my nails over this problem for days, looking for a conventional way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

It actually isn't too bad, just use an nginx config like this:

```
events {}

# assuming you want to serve your app on localhost:8080
# and assuming your webpack dev server runs on port 3000
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        # assuming you want to serve the app on localhost:8080
        listen 8080;
        client_max_body_size 50m;

        # webpack dev server
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            # use your port for your webpack dev server
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3000/;
        }

        # this is specifically needed for hot reload with webpack dev server
        location /sockjs-node {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;

            # 'host.docker.internal' is a docker dns record for your host machine's localhost,
            # and '3000' should be the port of your webpack dev server
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3000;

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
   }

    access_log /etc/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /etc/nginx/error.log debug;
}
```

And run nginx with a `./nginx.sh` that looks like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# path to your app's build directory
APP_BUILD_DIR=/path/to/my-app/build

# path of dir containing your nginx config
NGINX_CONF_DIR=$(pwd)

# name of your nginx conf file, relative to NGINX_CONF_DIR
NGINX_CONF_FILE=nginx.conf

# port at which nginx is serving your app
PORT=8080

# docker run docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/
# this will run an nginx container named 'nginx' as a daemon,
# and will mount NGINX_CONF_DIR in the container
docker run -d --name nginx \
  -v=$NGINX_CONF_DIR:/etc/nginx \
  -v=$APP_BUILD_DIR:/opt/base/my-app \
  -p=$PORT:$PORT nginx \
  nginx -c /etc/nginx/$NGINX_CONF_FILE -g "daemon off;"
```

And also a `mime.types` file in that directory that looks like [this one](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/mime.types).

So your directory structure should look like:

```
dir/
-- nginx.sh
-- nginx.conf
-- mime.types
-- ...
```

I'm assuming you're running your webpack dev server on your machine, not in a docker container? In my experience, I'd recommend that honestly. `npm` (or `yarn`) does its job so well that I haven't found a need to run my React apps in a container locally, even though I serve them through an `nginx` container.

Bonus: here's an nginx config if you want to run the same app, but serve the static bundle instead of the webpack dev server:

```
events {}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        # assuming you want to serve the app on localhost:8080
        listen 8080;
        client_max_body_size 50m;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            root /opt/base/my-app;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        # matches things like http://localhost:8080/build/static/js/2.d63c51de.chunk.js
        location /build/static/ {
            alias /opt/base/my-app/static/;
            try_files $uri $uri/;
        }
   }

    access_log /etc/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /etc/nginx/error.log debug;
}
```

Reference: [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40516288/webpack-dev-server-with-nginx-proxy-pass)

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for taking the time! I will test this and accept the answer as soon as I have it working :) Thanks. Right now, I have a working solution by running the dev server in a container. The advantage here is, that I can use the docker dns and define the dev server as an upstream server in nginx. Are there advantages to no running the node server not in a container as you propose?

Comment: I like building the frontend locally, outside of the container. It just seems easier. For a node server (other than webpack dev server) that needs to talk to other services (like a database), then I can see the advantages of running that using docker for its networking benefits. The beauty of docker is it's really up to you.

But you'll notice the line that says `proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3000;`? that `host.docker.internal` bit is the docker dns record for your true `localhost`. I hope that clears some things up for you.

Answer (score 1):

Dockerizing development server with HMR is not a trivial task.

Even preconfigured projects (with HMR and docker-ready) probably won't work at the beggining without additional adjustments. F.e. HMR expects `localhost` path while you can have app working on another IP/port (CORS problems). Some adjustments can be hard - patching packages on the fly - during build processes.

Try to run ready project before trying to setup your dream config. You can always run different servers for different parts (on different ports).

I'd start with [apollo-universal-starter-kit](https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-universal-starter-kit) - it contains node.js api/backend parts but can work with external one (configurable).

You can search for other react-HMR-ready solutions on Docker Hub. Try, get inspirations and knowledge ... have fun.

Answer (score 0):

For hot deploy to docker from local file system, specify the following options. Below is for docker running on windows 10 using powershell:

```
Set the environment variable
-e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true

Mount the volume of local machine into work directory in the container
-v ${pwd}:/<workdir in container>
 
E.g. : docker run -it --rm -p 5000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v ${pwd}:/app -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true <image id>
```